# performance/space sql: select into a @variable or into a #temp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My stored procedure gives me this error:

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.Large Object Storage System
>   object:  422213818384384' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY'
>   filegroup is full. "

In my query I'm using a lot of temporary tables.  I was wondering:

**What is better performance/space wise?** Is there a difference between using temporary tables or table variables with `SELECT INTO`?

An example:

```
select * 
into #temp1 from myTable

select * 
into #temp2 from #temp1

--then add some columns on temp2 and do some joins with temp1
```

Would this same `SELECT`/`JOIN` be better with `@temp1` and `@temp2`?

Comment: They should be equivalent.  Can you drop intermediary temp tables during the procedure's execution?

Comment: You can't `SELECT ...INTO` a table variable anyway.

Comment: my mistake, but you know what i mean. What about `set @var = 'select * from mytable'` vs `select ...into`

Comment: If tempdb ran out of space you need to get some more disc space soon. Sure your process may be bloated but if it is that close to running out of space it can and will happen again. And in my experience it is always at the worst possible time (during a kid's sporting event or the middle of the night). Allocate some disc space during the day and fix the code that is gobbling tempdb.

Comment: @ eric, I suppose i could drop some of them.

Comment: As far as space is concerned they will be the same. From a performance perspective they are not always the same. That is a pretty big topic but you can find lots of articles about the performance differences and when each is more appropriate.

Comment: I'm using ~ 10-12 temp tables in my stored procedure. I used `drop #table` as soon as it wasn't needed anymore. The thing is, i'm getting the same error. I don't have permission to alter the settings of the database or to add space or to put autogroth. What can i do?

Comment: 10-12 temp table. Oh then something wrong in your sp may be Lack in logic.

Comment: You need to sit back and think about rephrase the logic which you have used in sp to minimize the temp table and try to use CTE , Joins

Comment: the thing is this: the whole query works as it is. This error happens only when i put it in a stored procedure and try passing 3 parameters into 3 variables i have in the query

Comment: In regards to performance most times there's no difference between a table variable a and a temporary table. Sometimes there's huge differences and one or another ill be better but the only way to be sure is testing a lot. both ill use memory and (potentialy) disk. Anyway your error message suggests you look at your filegroup and check config vs avaible space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, in terms of both space and performance there's really no difference. There is a misconception that table variables are stored in RAM, which is incorrect. Both are allocated in tempdb space.

**Your error message indicates that the files used by tempdb have run out of allocated space, this probably needs addressing, running out of tempdb space can be a serious problem.**

A general rule of thumb is in the first instance avoid creating unnecessary objects (i.e. temporary tables / temporary data sets) and let SQL Server do its best at optimising the query in its most simple terms.

If you create two temporary tables, without seeing data/queries, that's gonna generate twice the amount of data so will likely worsen your issue.

From what you have posted, you should avoid the use of a temporary table / table variable and instead use plain queries. You can you subqueries or common table expressions to tame query complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Table variable and Temporary table are different though they both use TempDb.

Basic thumb rule for choosing table variable and temporary table is that you should choose table variable when you are dealing with less amount of data. Table variable don't involve themselves in transaction, locking and logging so they are comparatively faster ([usually good for less than 100 rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Other than that, temporary tables allows you to have indexes on it and they are just like normal table which exists on temporary database (TempDb).Do not create too many temporary tables because TempDb has to do various other operations other than handling user defined temporary objects. So, in your case you can opt for physical table with proper indexes. I believe, you are dealing with lots of blob objects, which in both the cases (i.e. table variable and temp table) use TempDb.